# Catching an exception in Slick 3.x

Tags: slick, slick-3.0

I'm trying to catch an SQL error in Slick 3.x. The code below doesn't print anything, but if traced under debug, it works fine (it prints the failure). What's wrong with this code?

```
object TestSlick extends App {

  val db = Database.forConfig("dbconfig")
  val sql = "update table_does_not_exist set zzz=1 where ccc=2"
  val q = sqlu"#$sql"

  db.run(q.asTry).map {result =>  
        result match {
                case Success(r) => println(r)
                case Failure(e) => {
                  println(s"SQL Error, ${e.getMessage}")
                  println("command:" + sql) 
                  throw e
                }
           }
      }

}
```

Comment: Probably your program terminates before the future finishes? Have you tried using `scala.concurrent.Await` to wait for the result (this blocks, but just to know if this is the reason)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works, a future is needed, thanks to lxx for the tip

```
    val future = db.run(q.asTry).map {result =>  
      result match {
        case Success(r) => println(r)
        case Failure(e) => {
          println(s"SQL Error, ${e.getMessage}")
          println("command:" + sql) 
          throw e
        }
    }
  }

  Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
```